# Gallary issue in marshmallow OS

Tags: samsung-galaxy-j5

I have updated Marshmallow OS from Lollipop OS in my galaxy J5 mobile. since I updated this, All folders are not seen in gallery. All images are displayed in only one folder. Also there is no option for moving images into another folder in gallery.so I wanted to know how to get back all the folders in gallery instead showing in one folder???

Answer (score 0):

Download a file manager from Google play. Open app and navigate to where your photos are stored. Make new folders and move photos in to them. I wood look at this list provided by Izzy https://android.izzysoft.de/applists/category/named/file_fileman

Comment: ES File Explorer has an exploitative reputation for bloat lately, by installing mal/adware that is hard to escape.

Comment: @SeanBurk maybe you [edit] your answer and adjust it accordingly? If you don't have a specific file explorer in mind, be welcome pointing [to my list](https://android.izzysoft.de/applists/category/named/file_fileman) for a selection :)

Comment: @ Izzy thanks I did edit it but it didnt changewill edit it again